# Rails 4 ActiveRecord has_many length condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

This problem seems simple but somehow I can't wrap my head around it using ActiveRecord queries:

I have 2 classes with a one to many relation

```
class Student

  belongs_to :school

end

class School

  has_many :students, inverse_of: :school

end
```

I want to create a scope which will fetch all the schools that have students (in other words, their student collection size is bigger then 0).

I know how to write this in SQL but ActiveRecord got me bumped.
I did manage to achieve this behaviour with this line:

```
School.joins(:students)
```

but I still want to know where can I specify a condition, something like:

```
School.where("students.length > ?", 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your actual question, rather an alternative, but you get a big performance boost on association counts using the 'counter_cache' feature in rails:

```
class Student
  belongs_to :school, :counter_cache => true
```

You also need to add a 'students_count' column to the schools table, with a default of 0. Then when an association is created/deleted this counter is automatically updated and allows simple queries like so:

```
School.where('students_count > ?, 0)
```